# Getting script component from a clicked object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the script component of an object once it has been clicked by a player, then run a specific function from the script when clicked. What I want to go is ether find the script based of the clicked objects name, or just a general way of getting scripts without the class name as it changes with each script. I've looked for way to do both but none work. I may just be implementing it bad so would love some help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after a method of identifying a specific component then I'd recommend adding an identifier into the component to search for such as a public variable.

That way you can easily get all the scripts on a GameObject and iterate through them checking for that public variable.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what type of objects you want to catch the clicks. If it’s 2d images, make sure you have RaycastTarget bool checked and use IPointerDownHandler interface.

If you gonna do it with 3d objects, then you should add some collider component to them and than make a raycast from camera view every time player clicks.

1. Get the ray from camera view - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html
2. Check the raycast with existing ray, putting the result to array - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
3. Better use separate layer for your objects so you can filter them among others
4. Use TryGetComponent to check if collision object has your target component - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.TryGetComponent.html

This way is more complicated than “OnMouseDown” event, but it is more reliable and debuggable, and also it fits perfectly for good common game architectures, unlike OnMouseDown event

Comment: What speaks against `OnMouseDown`? It basically already does the same things internally and works under the same conditions, so why implement something in a complicated way that comes already shipped built-in?

Comment: When we have an object containing some visuals (either 2d or 3d), its behavior is controlled by the attached logic (maybe with some public interface) and if we look at the code, we can understand this behavior. In a good architecture, high-level logic is defined by modules with single responsibility. OnMouseDown breaks this all by having external(confusing) logic details in a visual object and having this high-level rules(what to do with clicked objects) distributed among all such objects. Not easy do debug and read

Comment: One exception is a button - its only goal is to control external logic by calls